# Storing row data of a SQLite table in QR code

Tags: python, sqlite, qr-code

I am generating QR code for my Color Detection application

```
def qr_yellow(sl):
    "Select * from ColorDetector where sl = {}".format(sl)
    qr_y = str(c.fetchall())
    url = pyqrcode.create(qr_y)
    url.svg("CodeYellow{}.svg".format(sl), scale=8)
```

I am fetching the row data from SQLite using

```
c.execute("SELECT * from ColorDetector where sl =1")
```

and converting it into a string. The generated QR code stores the fetched data without any problem. But when I scan the code, the data isn't extracted. It only shows `[]`

This is the data I am storing in the QR:`[(1, 'YELLOW', '2019-12-30 17:42:42.971372')]`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fetch the data and have to convert it to string and then pass it to create function.

Also you should always specify the fields while fetching from the database instead of doing select *.

Comment: Converted the fetched data into string and stored it in the created QR code but when I scan it, the data is not shown only [].

Comment: @Gautham If, as you say, you have improved your code and got a step nearer, kindly update your question so folks can assist you better. Thank you.